# Two Jozabad's in 1 Chronicles 12:20?

Tags: textual-criticism, kjv, 1-chronicles

I found this interesting and wondered if anyone had anything to say about it.

**1 Chronicles 12**

> **20** As he went to Ziklag, there fell to him of Manasseh, Adnah, and ***Jozabad***, and Jediael, and Michael, and ***Jozabad***, and Elihu, and Zilthai, captains of the thousands that were of Manasseh.

I presume these are two different people named Jozabad but thought it interesting that they were not differentiated in any way.

Do we know if they are different? Is this a KJV issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little google search and found that there is also a mention of a Jozabad in 1 Chronicles 12:4 and it appears that this is one of the Benjamite archers who joined David at Ziklag and in 1 Chronicles 12:20 it([my source](http://www.biblestudytools.com/dictionary/jozabad/)) only gives a definition for one of them (I assume the other Jozabad), a chief of the tribe of Manasseh.

I looked at other versions of the Bible and all that I looked at had both listed in the same fashion as KJV, and that's when I dug a little deeper and found the information above, so it is not an issue with the KJV Bible.

They are two distinct people.

1. A Benjamite archer who joined David at Ziklag
2. A Chief of the tribe of Manasseh